# Why does Foursquare search not return venues closest to my specified location?

Tags: api, mobile, geolocation, foursquare

I'm noticing something odd with foursquare search API.  When I specify a latitude and longitude of a location in my city, I'm not getting venues that are closest to me.

For search parameters I'm using:

- ll = 47.620918,-122.318455 (a neighborhood in Seattle, WA)
- intent = browse
- radius = 48 280 (approx 30 miles)
- categoryId = 4d4b7105d754a06374d81259 (food), 4d4b7105d754a06376d81259 (nightlife)

> `venues/search?ll=47.620918,-122.318455&intent=browse&radius=42820&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259`

I would expect this query to return me venues that are closest to the specified lat+long location and in the food or nightlife categories.  This isn't what I'm seeing.  Instead, the first venue in the array is a venue that is 768 meters away, the second is 2162 meters, the third is 722 meters.

There are food and nightlife venues that are much closer than 700 meters to that latitude and longitude.

One could argue that I should take the results and sort them myself based on the `distance` attribute but this seems flawed for 2 reasons:

1. If the venue list being returned isn't closest to my location, I'm missing out on a lot of venues since they couldn't all fit within the max limit of the query results. So even if I sorted based on `distance` attribute, I'm only sorting venues that shouldn't be considered nearby.
2. The reason I specify a lat+long to the search API is to have foursquare do the heavy lifting for me on what is "nearby". If I need to sort then what's the point?  There's an argument to be made that foursquare shouldn't return venues that are more relevant to you, but this is why I'm using `intent=browse` instead of intent=checkin'

For `intent=browse`, the [docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) say:

> Find venues within a given area. Unlike the checkin intent, browse searches an entire region instead of only finding Venues closest to a point.

what am I doing wrong such that I'm not getting the closest venues return to the specified lat+long?

Answer (score 2):

Just like the docs say, when you use `intent=browse`, Foursquare doesn't **"only [find] Venues closest to a point."** When you use `intent=browse` with a ll/radius, imagine this as setting up a region and asking Foursquare for the "best" results from this region. It is not saying "find me the results starting at this ll growing until the radius."

In general, Foursquare search does not guarantee results in any particular order unless it's specified under the description for the `intent`, and unfortunately none of these specify that the results will be returned sorted by increasing radius.

Comment: Good eye, I misread the docs and read it instead as `..browse searches an entire region finding Venues closest to a point`.  The `instead of only` is a key part I missed :)

Comment: Do you have any idea on the best way to just get closest venues to a point?  It seems like a big omission in functionality.

Comment: `intent=checkin` will be your best bet here

Comment: thnx octopi.. might as well add intent=checkin in answer as solution for future visitors

Comment: checkin and browse seem to return the same results.  Is this an over site?  If I use there website the closest venue shows as expected. Making me crazy :/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old thread, just wanted to let people know that you can use sortByDistance=1 as parameter to sort venues the closest to the location.